# md-select get selected value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Подскажите пожалуйста! Мне дали верстку с применением фреймворка angular. Так вот я не могу получить при помощи javascript получить значение(value) выбранного итема. Просмотрел всё что предложил гугл и яндекс. но как получить значение при помощи

```
*document.getElementById("brandFilter")*
```

не нашел. Задача простая, вызвав функцию JS получить значения с контролов.

Comment: А так пробовали -  `document.getElementById('brandFilter').value` ?  Да и сам вопрос не очень понятен, для чего эти данные нужны? И добавьте код, откуда данные получаете.

Comment: вообщем движек сайта написан на asp мною лично. была заказана верстка сайта (которую как оказалось сделали на фрамеворке ангулар). у меня JS на самом минимальном уровне. могу вызывать события, менять значения в контролах, jqury запросы отправлять. так вот щас стоит задача сделать фильтр товара, а для этого в выподающих списках выбрать значения и нажать кнопку найти. сами контролы ангулар не серверные, потому мне придется скриптом собрать значения контролов и отправить jquery запрос сервису, который мне и вернет нужные данные.

Comment: Впринципе это развернутая картина задачи. Так вот мне нужно в процедуре JS получить значения контролов  md-select

Comment: document.getElementById('brandFilter').value , document.getElementById('brandFilter').selected, document.getElementById('brandFilter').ng-selected нигде нет значения

Comment: `<md-select name="fieldTm9" ng-model="fieldTm9" placeholder="Одежда">
                                                <md-option value="1">Item 1</md-option>
                                                <md-option value="2">Item 2</md-option>
                                                <md-option value="3">Item 3</md-option>
                                            </md-select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение можно получить с помощью чистого js, но **это неправильное решение**, но рабочее.
Получаем так у элемента `<md-select id="myId"  ...  >... </md-select>`:

```
document.getElementById('myId').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML
```

**Правильное решение** с использованием средств angular, но необходимо знать название контроллера (хотя в моем случае работает и получением элемента по ИД).

```
var get2 = function() {
  var data = angular //вызов функции angular
    .element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="TestCtrl"]')) //получение контроллера
    //.element(document.getElementById('myId')) //или этот вариант
    .scope() //получение значений контроллера
    .myOption; //сама переменная <md-select ng-model="myOption">
     console.log('data = ' + data.id); //значение из переменной
}
```

**Еще одно правильное решение** использовать angular:

```
$scope.upload = function(){
    console.log('myOption = '+$scope.myOption);
    var data = {myOption: $scope.myOption};
    $http.post('api/sendMyData', data).then(function (data) {
    }); }
```

Здесь создается функция, которая получает нужный элемент, который указан так: `<md-select ng-model="myOption"> ...` и отправляет его значение на сервер. Кнопка по которой срабатывает эта фукнция: `<input type="button" value="Press me" ng-click="upload()" />` . 
Рабочий пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
  <script data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    //вот правильный вариант, так можно получить (3 кнопка)
    var get2 = function() {
      var data = angular
        .element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="TestCtrl"]'))
        //.element(document.getElementById('myId'))
        .scope()
        .myOption;
         console.log('data = ' + data.id);
    }
    
    //неправильно: эта функция получает значение переменной и выводит в консоль на JS
    var get = function() {
      var val = document.getElementById('myId').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;
      console.log(val);      
    }
    
    angular.module("my-app", ["ngMaterial"])
      .controller("TestCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
      
       //Так должно выглядеть правильно:
      //начало: получить выбранное значение пользователя и отправить на сервер
        $scope.upload = function(){
          console.log('myOption = '+$scope.myOption);
          var data = {myOption: $scope.myOption};
          $http.post('api/sendMyData', data).then(function (data) {
          }); }
      //конец        
        $scope.optionLists = [          
          {id:1, val:'john'},
          {id:2, val:'max'},
          {id:3, val:'mark'},
          {id:4, val:'robin'}           
          ];
      $scope.myOption = $scope.optionLists[1];
      })
  </script>
</head>  
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div>
    <span>
        Value: {{myOption}}
      </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Default : </span>
    <md-select id="myId" ng-model="myOption" placeholder="Select a option">
      <md-option ng-value="option" ng-repeat="option in optionLists">{{ option.val }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <br>

  <input type="button" value="Так не правильно" onclick="get()" /> <!-- чистый JS -->
  <input type="button" value="Правильное выполнение" ng-click="upload()" /> <!-- angular -->
 <input type="button" value="Получить с помощью JS + angularJS" onclick="get2()" /> <!-- чистый JS + angular -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: может стоит добавить и правильное?

Comment: @Grundy я с радостью добавлю правильное решение, когда предоставят исходники (хотя бы код контроллера), где нужно "исправить", но автор знает JS на минимальном уровне и похоже не знает angular

Comment: я имел ввиду, в твоем коде, показать пример правильного

Comment: @Grundy  ок, сейчас переделаю

Comment: @Grundy обновил пример. И вопрос, можно в песочнице отправлять запросы(post), чтоб ошибка не появлялась?

Comment: [вот тема на мете](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288902/does-stack-overflow-have-an-echo-page-to-test-ajax-requests-inside-a-code-sni) вообще нельзя, но можно воспользоваться обходом из ссылки, либо использовать какой-нибудь сторонний echo-сервер

Comment: Что бы воспользоваться правильным средством, чувствую надо потратить много времени, что б разобраться. а неправильный в принципе на первое время преглянулся. Но есть проблема var val = document.getElementById('myId').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML; возвращает текст выбранного итема, а мне нужно значение которое я ложу в value. Кстати текст можно проще получить  var bv = document.getElementById("brandFilter").text;

Comment: Проблема в том что сильно затянута верстка была и осталось времени на целенаправленное кодирование, потому разбираться с angular отодвигается. Так как получить значение итема? :)

Comment: Добавил еще вариант `angular.element(document.getElementById('myId')).scope().myOption;` вот такой вариант, получаете нужный итем, где myOption это нужный элемент помеченный `ng-model="myOption"`, внутри находится объект.

Comment: @MrFylypenko огромное спасибо. Вариант с процедурой Get2  меня выричил. Конечно по окончанию проекта разберусь с этим фреймворком. Меня смущало то, что я заполнял этот контрол руками, а там как я погляжу все основано на репитерах и плизхолдерах, но все сработало.

Comment: я честно говоря не могу понять как код оформлять, но вот так я заполнял контрол

Comment: <md-select id="brandFilter" ng-model="fieldTm2"  placeholder="Select a option">
                                                <%
                                                    foreach (var i in brands)
                                                    {
                                                        bool flagB = true;
                                                        if (flagB)
                                                        {

Comment: Response.Write(" <md-option  selected value=\"" + i._value + "\">" + i._name + "</md-option>");
                                                            flagB = false;
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                            Response.Write(" <md-option value=\"" + i._value + "\">" + i._name + "</md-option>");

Comment: }
                                                     %>
                                            </md-select>

Comment: $('#btFilter').click(
            function () {               document.getElementById('brandFilter').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;
                var brandId = angular.element(document.getElementById('brandFilter')).scope().fieldTm2;
                var sfvId = angular.element(document.getElementById('stateFabricatorFilter')).scope().fieldTm1;
                document.location.href = "http://onlinestore.1gb.ru/Assortiment.aspx?node=2&sf=" + sfvId + "&b=" + brandId;
            });

Comment: Может кому наш диалог будет полезен. Если скопировать куски в среду разработки, то все будет понятно :)